# Comparing arrays and adding to different elements?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, elementwise-operations

```
z = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) 
x = np.array([4, 2, 3, 5])
n = 1
```

I want to compare these two arrays element wise and I want to add n to only those elements of z that are different to those of x.

Answer should be:

```
z = [2, 2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: Can you restore the original question and ask this as a new question? All the answers are completely irrelevant with your updates.

Comment: @Charles B Guess it would make sense to post a new question with those edits.

Comment: I have rolled back the edits that had changed the question to an entirely new form. Please post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another solution using np.where

```
#np.where checks if the condition is met, if yes set the value to z, otherwise z+n.
np.where(z==x, z,z+n)
Out[1257]: array([2, 2, 3, 5])
```

Comment: changed the question. Hope you can understand what i asked.

Answer (score 1):

Get a mask, scale it and do in-place add -

```
z += n*(z!=x)
```

Another approach using just the mask -

```
z[z!=x] += n
```

Sample runs -

```
In [176]: z = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4]) 
     ...: x = np.array([4, 2 ,3 ,5])
     ...: n = 1
     ...: 

In [177]: z += n*(z!=x)

In [178]: z
Out[178]: array([2, 2, 3, 5])

In [179]: z = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [180]: z[z!=x] += n

In [181]: z
Out[181]: array([2, 2, 3, 5])
```

Runtime test -

Approaches -

```
def app1(z, x, n):
    z += n*(z!=x)
    return z

def app2(z, x, n):
    z[z!=x] += n
    return z

def where_based(z, x, n): # @Allen's soln
    z = np.where(z==x, z,z+n)
    return z
```

Timings -

```
In [205]: z = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000000))
     ...: x = np.random.randint(0,9,(1000000))
     ...: n = 5
     ...: 
     ...: zc1 = z.copy()
     ...: zc2 = z.copy()
     ...: zc3 = z.copy()
     ...: 

In [206]: %timeit app1(zc1, x, n)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.82 ms per loop

In [207]: %timeit app2(zc2, x, n)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.95 ms per loop

In [208]: %timeit where_based(zc3, x, n)
100 loops, best of 3: 4.51 ms per loop
```